# Compare strings if contains in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to implement bash script that is reading from error log file and comparing strings with exceptions.

I am trying to compare it with `if`

```
error="[*] Text Text @ level 4: 'Some text' [parent = 'Not found'] "
exception="'Not found'"
if [[ "${error}" == *"${exception}"* ]]; then                                   
    echo "Yes it contains!"
fi
```

In this case I would expect the script to return "Yes it contains!", but it doesn't work as I expected. But it is true that my logs contain special character as well, anyone knows how should I handle that and compare it?

---

For me my `if` also works, but I might have something wrong in my nested loop. I am running the script in following process.

1. I have file with errors called `mylogfile.txt`:

   ```
   [*] Text Text @ level 4: 'Some text' [parent = 'Not found']
   ```
2. Then I have another file where I have exceptions inserted `exception.txt`:

   ```
   'Not found'
   ```
3. I do a loop over both files to see if I find anything:

   ```
   while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do 
       exception="$line"                       
       while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
           err="$line"                                                 
           if [[ "${err}" == *"${exception}"* ]]; then                                 
               echo "Yes it contains!"
           fi                  
       done < "mylogfile.txt"                  
   done < "exception.txt"
   ```

Comment: It works for me. Can you share the actual string that doesn't work? Maybe run it through `xxd` to show the special characters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your script, and it works when I run it.

That said, looping over files line by line in a shell script is a code smell. Sometimes it's necessary, but often you can trick some command or another into doing the hard work for you. When searching through files, think grep. In this case, you can actually get rid of *both* loops with a single grep!

```
$ grep -f exception.txt mylogfile.txt
[*] Text Text @ level 4: 'Some text' [parent = 'Not found']
```

To use it in an `if` statement, add `-q` to suppress its normal output and just check the exit code:

```
if grep -qf exception.txt mylogfile.txt; then
    echo "Yes, it's contained!"
fi
```

From the [grep(1) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

> **-f** *FILE*, **--file**=*FILE*
>
> - Obtain patterns from *FILE*, one per line. The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
>
> **-q**, **--quiet**, **--silent**
>
> - Quiet; do not write anything to standard output. Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` if you want exact match

```
if grep -q "$exception" <<< "$error"; then
    echo "Yes it contains!"
fi
```

Use `-i` switch to ignore case

Comment: There's no need to use `grep`; the pattern the OP is using should work.